# Winsock error 40009 vb6

Tags: vb6, winsock

```
 Winsock1.Connect "mail.website.com", 110

 Do Until received: DoEvents: Loop

 If sckError Then MsgBox "An error occured trying to connect to server": Exit Sub

 sendMsg "USER username"  ' Send UserName
 If sckError Then MsgBox "Error with username": Exit Sub

 sendMsg "PASS password"   ' Send Password
 If sckError Then MsgBox "Error with password": Exit Sub


' Get Number of Messages and total size in bytes
 sendMsg "STAT"
 x = InStr(Message$, " "): b = InStrRev(Message$, " ")
 messages = Val(Mid$(Message$, x + 1, b - x))
 Size = Val(Mid$(Message$, b + 1))
 If messages = "0" Then
 MsgBox "no new messages"
 GoTo l
 End If

 For a = 1 To messages
    Winsock1.Tag = "RETR"
    Open "C:\Windows\Temp\eMail-" & a & ".eml" For Binary Access Write As #1

    sendMsg "RETR " & a
    List1.AddItem "eMail-" & a & ".eml"
  Next

  Winsock1.Tag = ""

 Next
l:
Winsock.Close
```

---

When i run this the first time it works perfectly, but when i try to run it a second time w/o closing the app, it gives me the 40009 error. I'm thinking im trying to send data before its connected. is there a way to see if winsock is connected? somthing like

if winsock1.state = true then...

Answer (score 0):

You didn't list all of the code, but I'm guessing that the variable `received` is not reset, causing you to fall through directly to the `sendMsg "USER username"` code early.  You have to let the cinnection actually happen/complete before you can start writing to the socket.

Comment: How do i go about doing that is there something like

Comment: It would be easier to assist if you could post more of the code.  But in general you will want to wait until the connection is completed beofre doing I/O.  There is a Connect event to inform you when this happens.